# Which R packages are suitable for plotting disease transmission over time?

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I am trying to find a way to plot a disease transmission tree that allows me to:

- plot the tree over a timeline (a timeline spanning 2 months)
- specify the shape and colour of the nodes in the tree (so that you can easily identify which nodes belong to the same household for example)
- format the link between the nodes (dashed lines, two way arrows, solid lines...etc.)
- plot "stray branches" that aren't linked to the root/parent node.

The dataset I am working with is relatively small (22 nodes) so I don't mind working with a package that is a bit fiddly!

I have thought about using phylogeny trees, but I'm uncertain whether they will allow me to plot stray nodes. Which package would be most suitable for this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [DiagrammeR](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/).  I don't have much experience, but it did what I needed to do and I know I barely scratched the surface of what it can do.